# How to customize association methods in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Let's say I have a users and projects.
Than I create a 1:m association between them.

```
const User = sequlize.define("user", {...})
const Project = sequelize.define("project". {...})

User.hasMany(Project, { as: "projects" })
```

Than sequelize creates the

```
addProject
```

method for me automatically.

In other scenarios I might want a custom function for that.

For example might I want to check if this user is allowed to pick up
the project.

In other scenarios I might also want to prevent sequelize from
adding these association methods to my object.

My questions:

1. Is there a way to create a custom association method,
   if not can I at least define a validation method?
2. Can I prevent sequelize from adding a specific association method?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is there a way to create a custom association method, if not can I at least define a validation method?

As i know there is no way to create custom associated method. All customization you can achieve through `scope` field. For example:

```
  models.User.belongsToMany(
    models.List,
    {
      through: {
        model: models.UserList,
        scope: {
          owner: true,
        },
      },
      as: {
        singular: 'OwnedList',
        plural: 'OwnedLists',
      },
    });
```

So when I call `user.addOwnedList(...)` property `owner` on `UserList` will be `true` by default. Same for 1:m associations, some fields may be set through `scope`. Also you can have different associatin scopes and divide them by `as` field.
For example:

```
  models.User.belongsToMany(
    models.List,
    {
      through: models.UserList,
      as: {
        singular: 'List',
        plural: 'Lists',
      },
    });
```

So to find all `List` will use `user.getLists(...)` and to share list with other user will use "user2.addList(...)" so property `owner` will be `false`. And to get only owned lists will use `user.getOwnedLists(...)` result SQL will be like `WHERE "owner"=true` by defaut.

> 2. Can I prevent sequelize from adding a specific association method?

You can't prevent creation of method, but you can delete it immediately after association. For example:

```
user.associate = function (models) {
  models.User.belongsToMany(
    models.List,
    {
      through: models.UserList,
      as: {
        singular: 'List',
        plural: 'Lists',
      },
    });

  models.User.belongsToMany(
    models.List,
    {
      through: {
        model: models.UserList,
        scope: {
          owner: true,
        },
      },
      as: {
        singular: 'OwnedList',
        plural: 'OwnedLists',
      },
    });

  /**
   * Deleting method createList to prevent list creation
   * without owner
   * List must be created using user.createOwnedList
   */
  delete user.prototype.createList;
};
```

So when someone calls method `user.createList` it will result in `undefined is not a function` error. It's not perfect solution but at least it adds more security and data consistency without complex constraints.